# Peewee query based on columns known only at runtime

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee

I'm currently constructing an SQL query (in Python) along the lines of:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (" + \
    " OR ".join([firstType+'=1' for firstType in firstTypes]) + \
    ") AND (" + \
    " OR ".join([secondType+'=1' for secondType in secondTypes]) + \
    ")"
```

which, given two lists `firstType=['B','F']` and `secondType=['a','d']` produces the query

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ( ('B'=1 OR 'F'=1) AND ('a'=1 OR 'd'=1) )
```

which I execute with `Table.raw(query)`.

I know how to produce that particular query in Peewee, something like:

```
Table.select().where( (Table.B=1 | Table.F=1) & (Table.a=1 | Table.d=1) )
```

but the problem is that I don't know the contents of the two lists (i.e. the columns) in advance.

How do I construct a Peewee query dynamically based on (potentally many) columns which are known only at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy -- you just use `field = getattr(MyModel, 'field_name')` or alternatively `field = MyModel._meta.fields['field_name']`.

Then you would presumably generate a list of expressions:

```
data = {'field_a': 1, 'field_b': 33, 'field_c': 'test'}
clauses = []
for key, value in data.items():
    field = MyModel._meta.fields[key]
    clauses.append(field == value)
```

To *AND* all the clauses together, you can:

```
import operator
expr = reduce(operator.and_, clauses) # from itertools import reduce in Py3
```

To *OR* them:

```
import operator
expr = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
```

The last step is just to drop it into the `where()` clause of a query.

Comment: You never fail to impress, @coleifer

Comment: Glad my answer helped.

Comment: @coleifer, isn't there any other solution for today? Without accessing "protected" member :) This one works perfectly, just wondering if something more elegant appeared.